# R: Loop through a list of csv files to alter date format and create XTS objects

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to import a file of csv's and ultimately convert them to XTS objects in R.

Each individual csv is of the format:

```
Date       Open    High    Low     Close    Volume
18-Jun-99   2.35    2.35    2.35    2.35    34000
21-Jun-99   2.35    2.35    2.35    2.35    57317
22-Jun-99   2.35    2.35    2.35    2.35    7000
```

The issue here is the date, however a function within lubridate converts this easily. For an individual csv my process is as follows:

```
require(xts)
CAR.csv <- read.csv("CAR.csv", header = TRUE)
require(lubridate)
CAR.csv$Date <- dmy(CAR.csv$Date)
CAR.csv <- read.zoo(CAR.csv)
CAR.csv <- as.xts(CAR.csv)
```

However I need to do this for many hundred files so I'd like to be able to loop through them all. I'm stuck at this point now:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data")
library(xts)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i], header = TRUE))
```

I don't really know how to apply the dmy function to only the date column within a loop and I would love any assistance that could point me in the right direction.

A previous version of my loop for csv files with the correct date format was this:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data")
library(xts)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
toDate <- function(x) as.Date(x, origin = "2005-01-01")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], as.xts(read.zoo((temp[i]), header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = toDate)))
```

In terms of a fully reproducible example here is a [sample folder](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=18405613365313323268) of csv's if required, however I suspect this is straight forward for most competent R users.

I would certainly love some advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setwd("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data")
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

load_file <- function(file_name) {
  csv_file <- read.csv(file_name, header = TRUE)
  csv_file$Date.Time <- dmy(csv_file$Date.Time)
  csv_file <- read.zoo(csv_file)
  csv_file <- as.xts(csv_file)

  csv_file
}

list_of_files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

data <- lapply(X = list_of_files, FUN = load_file)
```

The code works by defining a function that when given the name of a file in the working directory, reads it and then performs the transformations required on that one file. Note that in your example data the date column is called `Date.Time` so I have changed the code to reflect this.

Instead of using a loop, I have applied the function to each individual filename in the list of filenames, using the base `apply(...)` function. The output of this operation is a list containing the transformed data you're after. To access each data object, use `data[[1]]` etc.

Comment: Hello @Alex, thanks for your help. Do think using a function and lapply would allow the csv files to be assigned to individual XTS objects within the global environment as opposed to a single object? Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure. Each element of the `data` list in my code above is an individual XTS object within the global environment. You could name each element - e.g. `names(data) <- list_of_files` so that you can then refer to them such as `data['CDM.csv']` or `data$CDM.csv`, or you could just re-assign them to other names - e.g. `first_xts_objext <- data[[1]]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to assign each individual XTS object to a distinct object in the global environment, you could change the last line of the `load_file` function to be `assign(file_name, csv_file, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. This should leave you with objects in the global environment with names such as `CDM.csv`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your for-loop to what you would do with a single file:

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)){
  assign("new.tmp", read.csv(temp[i], header = TRUE))
  new.tmp$Date <- dmy(new.tmp$Date)
  new.tmp <- read.zoo(new.tmp)
  assign(temp[i],as.xts(new.tmp))
}
```

This might cost a little bit of time, since you copy the whole object once more often in each loop-iteration, but I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this method @snaut. I like this approach. Would it be possible to adjust your loop so each individual csv becomes a seperate XTS object in the global environment? Many thanks

Comment: this should be the case in this loop, if run in the global environment, `assign(temp[i], value)` assigns value to the variable with the name `temp[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer to initialize a list before the loop, read and process that files, and then store them back in the list.

The main advantage of such approach is:

1. Keeping your environment clean
2. Ability to use the `lapply` to do the same processing for all the files loaded
3. Ability to extract/process a single file by simply indexing it either by filename or index

**Code Sample:**

```
paths.allFiles = list.files(pattern="*.csv") # Equivalent to "temp"
processedCSVs = list()

for(path.oneFile in paths.allFiles){ # hint: you can access the file names directly without indexing
  csv =  as.xts(read.zoo(path.oneFile, header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = toDate))
  processedCSVs[path.oneFile] = csv
}

lapply(processedCSVs, nrow) # Returns all the nrows of all files
nrow(processedCSVs[[1]]) # Returns the nrows of the indexed file only
```